# How to bind a <input type = "text" .. with my property in ViewMode

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, modelbinders, mvc-editor-templates, custom-model-binder

How to bind to an `input[type='text']` field with a property of type `Subsidiary`
When user register a party, one of the fields is the subsidiary that was the party

Instead of putting a DropDown, Select or Radio I put a `input[type='text']` field
and when the user starts typing the name of the subsidiary, the [autocomplete of jQueryUI](http://jqueryui.com/demos/autocomplete/) shows the list of subsidiaries have filtered

### Code

To accomplish these tasks, I have:

**ViewModel**

```
public class PartyViewModel
{       
    [UIHint("SubsidiarySelect")]
    public Subsidiary Subsidiary { get; set; }
}
```

**HTML**

HTML generated by EditorTemplates of `SubsidiarySelect`

```
<input id="Subsidiary_Title" name="Subsidiary.Title" type="text" value="">
<input id="Subsidiary" name="Subsidiary" type="hidden" value="00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000">
```

`#Subsidiary_Title` > is used to display the selected subsidiary
`#Subsidiary` > saves the selected code Guid of subsidiary

**Controller**

My control is nothing special.
I would like the property `Subsidiary` in my `PartyViewModel` class would have filled.

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Nova(PartyViewModel model)
{
    if (ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        //.....
    }
}
```

### Questions

I thought of creating a `SubsidiaryBinder: IModelBinder` so that when the post was made, I would fill the `Subsidiary` property with the Database values (as have the ID)

1. If this is the solution, then how to create a binder to run only in the class PartyViewModel
2. How to automatically retrieve the values ​​from the database for the `Subsidiary` property class `PartyViewModel` when making a post?

Comment: Not sure if placing code calling the repository into a binder is the right way to go. If all you have on the client side is a list of `Subsidiary_Title` without their matching guids then you still should try to make that call to the database through the intented layers of your application. Given a choice between a binder making a call to the database or a controller post-action, I would propably be more leaning torwards making that call in the controller post-action. Then again, that depends on how you application is layerd I suppose.

Answer (score 0):

You can set the Binder for your `PartyViewModel` on Application_Start in global.asax

#### Sample

**Your Binder**

```
public class PartyViewModelBinder : DefaultModelBinder
{
    public override object BindModel(ControllerContext controllerContext, ModelBindingContext bindingContext)
    {
        // ... do something,
        // for example, retieve values from database 
        return base.BindModel(controllerContext, bindingContext);
    }
}
```

**Register in global.asax**

```
ModelBinders.Binders.Add(typeof(PartyViewModel), new PartyViewModelBinder());
```